# How to get delivery count of message node nats streaming server

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nats.io

While using node nats streaming server there is once scenario where I want to prevent message from getting again and again in subscriber in case of error from service
There could be a possible solution where I can acknowledge message while handling exception however there could be scenario in which exception is not handled properly in that case service would get message again and again till it gets redeployed with potential fix, !